# Using Take in SQL LINQ query: syntactic differences cause a hang and SQLException?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm new to C# and LINQ, but the latter is pretty cool. Except I can't figure out what is going on here:

I have the following piece of code, which runs as expected; it sorts and selects the top 100 records:

```
IEnumerable<workerLog> query =
    (from record in _gzClasses.workerLogs                
    orderby record.workerID, record.timeStamp ascending                
    select record).Take(100);

foreach(var record in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record.timeInSession.ToString());
}
```

but when I do the following, the same lines print, but then the program hangs a bit and a SQLException is thrown saying the server timed out.

```
IEnumerable<workerLog> query =
    from record in _gzClasses.workerLogs                
    orderby record.workerID, record.timeStamp ascending                
    select record;

foreach(var record in query.Take(100))
{
    Console.WriteLine(record.timeInSession.ToString());
}
```

What in the world is the difference here? Does it have something to do with the way LINQ queries are executed? Coming from the Java world, it makes no sense.

Comment: Try t run sql profiler and see what queries are being executed. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

```
IEnumerable<workerLog> query =
```

By forcing it to `IEnumerable<WorkerLog>`, you have broken "composition", which means SQL server thinks you have asked for **all** the data, and **at the receiver** you will choose to only care about the first 100 rows. If you use `IQueryable<WorkerLog>` instead (or just `var`), then it can "compose" the Take(100) into the SQL and issue:

```
select top 100 ...
```

Note that in the first example, you only force it to `IEnumerable<WorkerLog>` **after** it has composed, so that works ok.... ish.

Basically, `IQueryable<T>` is the composable API that makes interesting TSQL from multiple operations. `IEnumerable<T>` is LINQ-to-Objects, which does the filtering / etc in c# rather than in SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I must have just pulled `IEnumerable` out of my butt.

If I switch to `var`, however, will there be problems casting it back to `workerLog` in the `foreach` loop?

Also, is there something specific about `IEnumerable` that would have caused the SQL errors?

Comment: @AndrewMao no, there's no issue using `var`; `var` just means "compiler: you can see what this is returning - figure out the type yourself", which means it will be `IQueryable<WorkerLog>` - so no issues at all knowing that each is a `WorkerLog`. Re "something specific" - yes; how many rows are there in the table? Querying 2 million rows (or whatever) may cause a timeout when querying 100 rows might not.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the var issue. I'm trying to ask another LINQ-based question but it appears my account has been banned for some reason :(